# Webfaction redirect no-WWW to WWW (static app, htaccess file)

Tags: redirect, webfaction

In webfaction, I want to redirect mysite.com to www.mysite.com

I have the following:

- A subdomain www.mysite.com. It has a website with a Django app.
- A subdomain mysite.com. It has a website which has a Static/CGI/PHP app. This app is called redirect.
- In webapps/redirect I  have created a file .htaccess. (BTW, this kept "disappearing". In ssh use ls -a to see that it is actually there.)

This file look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Also tried with ^ in front of mysite.com$)

When I go to mysite.com I see the default page "Hello, World" instead of what I see when I go to www.mysite.com

Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours of doing other stuff, it now works without my having changed anything.

Comment: I think webfaction's systems have a delay on these files. Really annoying.